# emeditor not responsive when replace with nexline regex \n

Tags: emeditor

I met such a problem, when i want to replace millions or more matching words with new line regex \n ( to split the content into millions lines)
.
The replacing tasks looks took a very long time. and looks no responding.

I'm Using the lastest version.in window 10.

Can you check if this can be solved ?

Comment: Try do it in multithread task

Comment: Please write a sample regex to reproduce the issue.

Comment: for example. replacing 10 million {"_index  with \n{"_index

Comment: small results replace no problem. but huge results .quite slow and not reponsive.

Comment: `{"_index` doesn't look a regex. Please select `Escape Sequence` in the `Replace` dialog box if not regex. Which version of EmEditor are you using? Please also try `No Wrap` settings (Ctrl+1).

Comment: {"_index not a regx.  i Just put a regex \n to get new line.

Comment: {"_index not a regx.  i Just put a regex \n to get new line. Using Version 20.6.909. no wrap settings selected.. anywa, I solved the prolbem by extract matching content to new file. Thank you!

Comment: That's what I mean. Even if you just need to use 
`\n` as a replacement expression, `\n` is also an escape sequence. It will be much faster if you select `Escape Sequence` instead of `Regular Expressions`.

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is an escape sequence as well as a regular expression. Select `Escape Sequence` instead of `Regular Expressions` in the **Replace** dialog box to increase the replacement speed.